# Cordova: Store data in database persistently

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing an app with Cordova for Android and iOS.
The app needs to store data in a database and use them again later (also after a reboot of the mobile device). So I need to store the data persistently. There are many Cordova / PhoneGap plugins for Web SQL, but all plugins I found had the problem that the database is not stored persistently (i. e. the database is deleted for example when I reboot the phone). Can you recommend a plugin to use for my purpose? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SQLite database for this, a lot of documentation can be found in the README for [this plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which is **super simple** and **secure** to use for long term data persistence is the **Secure Storage Function of the Intel Security API** which comes as a [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/AppSecurityApi/com-intel-security-cordova-plugin) and supports Android and iOS.   https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506844